# Unity GIT - managing `.meta` files / Working with multiple repositories in Unity

Tags: unity, git

**(Original Question) →** ScriptableObject has empty inspector after cloning from git

After cloning repository from git the data from the `ScriptableObject` asset isn't there.

An example of the problem:
[image: Empty scriptableobject inspector]

A working example:
[image: Working scriptableobject inspector]

I assume the problem is in `.gitignore` because there is `*.meta`, so the data of `ScriptableObject` is lost. Is there a way to configure `.gitignore` to leave the `*.meta` files in some subdirectory?

Comment: You generally do not want to ignore .meta files in your project. These are where Unity stores the UIDs that scenes/prefabs/etc. use to express references. If a new user syncs your project, or if you need to pull it down from scratch after a mishap with your working copy, all of this UID referencing information will be missing and Unity won't know what textures or materials or scripts belong on which scene objects.

Comment: @DMGregory Right! But not generally, you might want to ignore them. For example, I have a `.git` repository where I store the code that I reuse all the time for different projects. So I can't put project specific data to that repository, I need this repository to have clean history and no redundant files. So when I am working on some project, I might need some feature in there and I would like to improve it and push to remote for other projects to have it too, so I must not override `.meta` files in different projects after pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, but I felt like sharing it with people who could encounter the same problem. And also add additional information, solutions and troubleshooting that I have found/made.

---

Yes, you can ignore specific files and folders as well as make exceptions to work with 2+ repositories in same unity project without losing references on objects because of lost `.meta` files.

1. You can do `Project/.gitignore` and `Project/Assets/SpecificFolder/.gitignore` which will override the parent `Project/.gitignore`. *Look tip **(4)** to get the opposite result*
2. To exclude `.meta` files but save `ScriptableObject`s data - add `*.meta` and `!*.asset.meta` to your `.gitignore` which will exclude all `.meta` files except the ones that are `.asset.meta`.
3. If you have a sub-folder that is a `.git` repository and you want it to be added as sub-folder to remote`(not as a link or submodule)`. You can first add some specific file from that repository folder `git add Assets/my-git-repo-i-use/Controllers`. Now your `my-git-repo-i-use` isn't anymore considered as `submodule` by your main `.git`. So you can add everything in there **(4)** including `.meta` files even if you have `.gitignore` that ignores `*.meta`.
4. If you have a sub-folder that has `.gitignore` with, for example, `*.meta` because you have the code that you reuse for every project there, but you don't want to store specific data for specific project via pushing meta files - then you can ignore the sub-folder's `.gitignore` from/by(haven't found a solution yet - in the parents `.gitignore` I have tried `!Assets/my-git-repo-i-use/**` - didn't work for me. I will update the asnwer, though maybe someone in the comments will have the solution to this). For now you can → 1. Just rename `.gitignore` in sub-folder to something like `.gitignoreC` to use root `.gitignore` rules. || 2. Create an empty folder, call it something like `Archived`, move sub-folder's `.gitignore` there.

**(4)** - useful/related information:

- [Stack Overflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719574/is-it-possible-to-ignore-gitignore-rules-in-subdirectory)
- [Stack Overflow 1 - possible solution but it didn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24944451/6603717)
- [Stack Overflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788691/override-gitignore-in-subfolder)
- [Stack Overflow 3 - ignore without .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore)